# SQLAlchemy update record with case clause and enum

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy, python-3.4

I have defined the following model and `enum`:

```
class StatusEnum(enum.Enum):
    NEW = 'NEW'
    PROCESSED = 'PROCESSED'
    IN_PROGRESS = 'IN_PROGRESS'

class RequestLog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'request_log'

    ...
    status = Column(Enum(StatusEnum))
    ...
```

I'm trying to update the record in the following way:

```
>>> session.query(RequestLog).filter(RequestLog.id.in_([8])).update(
{'status': case(
    [(RequestLog.attempt_done_count == RequestLog.attempt_count - 1, StatusEnum.PROCESSED)],
    else_=StatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS)},
synchronize_session=False)
```

During this, I received an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'StatusEnum' [SQL: 'UPDATE request_log SET status=CASE WHEN (request_log.attempt_done_count = request_log.attempt_count - %(attempt_count_1)s) THEN %(param_1)s ELSE %(param_2)s END WHERE request_log.id IN (%(id_1)s)'] [parameters: {'param_2': <StatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS: 'IN_PROGRESS'>, 'attempt_count_1': 1, 'param_1': <StatusEnum.PROCESSED: 'PROCESSED'>, 'id_1': 8}]
```

Comment: It'd seem that the query compiler is able to convert enumerated objects, if passed directly as a value, but does not if they're a part of an SQL expression. Could not find any references as to whether or not this is by design, and could not find [any issues](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues?q=Enum%20adapt) on the topic. Consider opening one?

Comment: Check your SQLA version

Comment: `>>> sqlalchemy.__version__`
'1.1.11'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a simple Python enum object bind value the [bind processor of `sqltypes.Enum`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py#L1437) is run, which [uses the string name of the enum object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) in question:

```
In [27]: session.query(RequestLog).filter(RequestLog.id.in_([8])).update(
    ...:     {'status': StatusEnum.NEW},
    ...:     synchronize_session=False)
2017-07-24 15:15:43,848 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE request_log SET status=%(status)s WHERE request_log.id IN (%(id_1)s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:UPDATE request_log SET status=%(status)s WHERE request_log.id IN (%(id_1)s)
2017-07-24 15:15:43,848 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'status': 'NEW', 'id_1': 8}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'status': 'NEW', 'id_1': 8}
Out[27]: 0
```

This does not seem to happen recursively for SQL expressions though, so in your `case()` the enum object bind values are passed to psycopg, which does not know how to handle them. To emulate the behaviour in an SQL expression you can manually pass the [names of the enum objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes), with an appropriate cast:

```
In [60]: session.query(RequestLog).filter(RequestLog.id.in_([8])).update(
    ...:     {'status': case(
    ...:         [(true(), StatusEnum.PROCESSED.name)],
    ...:         else_=StatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS.name).cast(RequestLog.status.type)},
    ...:     synchronize_session=False)
2017-07-24 15:40:52,853 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE request_log SET status=CAST(CASE WHEN true THEN %(param_1)s ELSE %(param_2)s END AS statusenum) WHERE request_log.id IN (%(id_1)s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:UPDATE request_log SET status=CAST(CASE WHEN true THEN %(param_1)s ELSE %(param_2)s END AS statusenum) WHERE request_log.id IN (%(id_1)s)
2017-07-24 15:40:52,853 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param_2': 'IN_PROGRESS', 'param_1': 'PROCESSED', 'id_1': 8}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'param_2': 'IN_PROGRESS', 'param_1': 'PROCESSED', 'id_1': 8}
Out[60]: 0
```

It is unsightly and I'm somewhat sure there exists a better method, but for the time being this was the best I could come up with.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. I had actually try `cast`, `type_coerce`, `literal` and other option but without any success. I was limited in time so I just iterate it in loop. I know it bad approach but it works.

Comment: Any particular error / reason it doesn't work for you? While testing my local Postgres run that happily.

Comment: `session.query(RequestLog).filter(RequestLog.id.in_([8])).update({'status': case([(RequestLog.attempt_done_count == RequestLog.attempt_count - 1, StatusEnum.PROCESSED)], else_=StatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS).cast(RequestLog.status.type)}, synchronize_session=False` I got the same `can't adapt type 'StatusEnum'`.

Comment: psql (9.4.9)
psycopg2==2.7.1

Comment: I thought it might be that. Instead of passing the enum object, pass for example `StatusEnum.PROCESSED.name`, which passes the string name of the enum object. That way you manually do what SQLAlchemy does for plain enum object bind values.

Comment: Seems it works `StatusEnum.PROCESSED.name` thank you. Make "answer" from your comment and I will mark it like answer. :-)

Comment: But, it was in this very answer to begin with.

Comment: Yes true. Sorry my bad.